# Gitlab-Runner runs without port direction

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab-runner inside a container and register from that container.

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

I started my container with that commands. And everything works as expected. However as you can see i didn't mention about ports inside my commands. So is it using something else(i dont know what)? It still work fine even if i changed the network(my custom network).

I am just a newbee about docker but the definition about container says that: each container has an isolated environment and cant communicate outside without port directions. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to bind a port to the hoster because the runner will fetch your Gitlab answer periodically and Gitlab will give it jobs to do.

The runner initiates the connexion so you don't have to set an entry point.